# Modify unplotted gList list

Tags: r

If i have a gList that I have not plotted yet, can i modify the text in it.

Example:

```
library('VennDiagram')
temp <- venn.diagram(list(A=0,B=0),euler.d=FALSE, scale=FALSE, filename=NULL)
```

Here temp is a unplotted gList, that I can plot by

```
grid.draw(temp)
```

But what If i wanted to modify the text objects (incl nubers) before plotting it but after creating the gList object. E.g can I change the values within the venn diagram after the gList have been created?

I know I can do it with grid.edit() if I plot the venn diagram first, but that is not an option.

in

```
str(temp)
```

it is the  ..$ label i want to change.

In advance - thanks.

Comment: What are "inkl nubers"? I'm pretty sure I can do it easily with standard R if you tell me what part of the complex argument you want modified. Please refer to specific sections in `str(temp)`.

Comment: @DWin I think one of the problems is that the object is a grid graphical object (gList) so it seemed hard (to me at least) to flatten and unflatten it using base functions like `as.relistable` and `unlist` etc and then changing elements using subsetting. They didn't work.

Comment: DWin - I have added the specific section in the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it, but it's a bit of a hack. Also I don't know if you can subset a list by more than one element at once, so you might have to change each label by hand individually. Basically I inspected the plot and then had a look at the structure of the `temp` object and found where in the object the labels are stored. I then got the indices of the list elements which are actually text objects and used subsetting to edit these in place to something else. The only thing is I found I had to do each one at a time which is a pain if you have lots. You can try this and I hope it helps:

```
unlist( sapply(temp,'[[',"label") )
[1] "0" "0" "1" "A" "B"

# Make index of which top-level elements of list are text elements
x <- !sapply( sapply(temp,'[[',"label") , is.null )
ind <- seq.int(length(x))
ind <- ind[x]


# Subset and change each one in place
`[[`(`[[`( temp , ind[1] ), "label") <- "WAS"
`[[`(`[[`( temp , ind[2] ), "label") <- "BY"
`[[`(`[[`( temp , ind[3] ), "label") <- "CHANGED"
`[[`(`[[`( temp , ind[4] ), "label") <- "THIS"
`[[`(`[[`( temp , ind[5] ), "label") <- "ME"

# Plot with new labels
grid.draw(temp)
```

[image]

Comment: You are rigth - it is a bit of a hack - but it works. Thanks!

Comment: @KristofferVKKnudsen You are welcome! If this satisfactorily answered the question you may want to consider accepting the answer so that this will not appear on the unanswered questions list anymore, but it's up to you. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the package doesn't follow the grid recommendations to make grobs easily accessible by name etc.

In an interactive session where you can find the names on the display list with `grid.ls()`, you can do the following:

```
venn <- gTree(children=temp, name="venn")
grid.edit("venn::GRID.text.17", label="this is a new label")
```

(obviously 17 is unique to my session at a given state; unnamed grobs are indexed automatically by grid)

If there was a consistent (reproducible) naming scheme, you could define your own `gTree` wrapping the `gList` with an `editDetails` method to edit recursively the children labels.

Comment: `editGrob(venn, "GRID.text.7", label='new')` also works, but it's annoying to have to wrap something in a gTree in order to edit it. Is there a better way?