# Removing plot background to make it png

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork

I have a VennDiagram that I wish to plot on top of a chart. I already know I can do this with `patchwork::inset_element()`. The problem, though, is that the VennDiagram has a white blackground which is default to R Studio plots. I've been looking into `magick` and trying to remove the Diagram's background, or make it transparent, so it'd essentially become a png image and wouldn't overlap with the chart data, but I can't figure it out how to do this. Could anyone land me a hand???

```
pacman:: p_load (ggplot2, VennDiagram, patchwork)
```

### Venn Diagram Example:

```
myvd <- draw.quad.venn (area1 = 300, area3 = 70, area4 = 2, area2 = 1,
                        n12 = 0, n13 = 0, n14 = 0,
                        n23 = 0, n24 = 1, n34 = 1,
                        n123 = 0, n124 = 0, n134 = 0, n234 = 0, n1234 = 0,
                        category = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                        fill = c ("orange", "yellow", "pink", "lightblue"), lty = "blank")
```

### Chart Example:

```
data <- data.frame(name=c("A","B","C","D","E"), value=c(3,12,5,18,45))
chart <- ggplot(data, aes(x=name, y=value)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", width=0.2)
```

### What it looks like:

[image]

### But...!

I really needed to have this Venn Diagram's background removed, so it wouldn't overlap with the chart data... and I can't figure out how to do this =/

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a working code example and a snippet of your data or some fake data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```r
chart + inset_element(vd + theme_void(), 0, 0.4, 0.9, 0.9)
```

[image]

Or, if you are using `VennDiagram` instead of `ggVennDiagram`, try:

```r
chart +
  lapply(vd, annotation_custom, xmin = 1, xmax = 4.5, ymax = 45, ymin = 15)
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work =// sorry, I was editing my answer, but I'm actually using VennDiagram::draw.quad.venn() to plot my venn diagram

Comment: @not_ginn I was replicating your "desired plot". Anyway, see my update for how to achieve this with your other plot type.

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward approach is to use the `void` [theme of ggplot](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/index.html#themes) like this:

```
vd <- ggVennDiagram(x, theme = 'void')
ggplot(...) + ## your main plot code here
  inset_element(vd, .5, .5, 1, 1)
```

Comment: But I plotted my venn diagram with VennDiagram::draw.quad.venn() and it doesn't have that option. I opted for this package because I couldn't manually set the values with ggVennDiagram

Comment: Then, please, remove the Venn Diagramm example from your OP (you're using `ggVennDiagram` there).

Comment: Sorry...! Ok. Done

Comment: From this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16039437/modify-unplotted-glist-list I guess it might get hacky to directly set a transparent background. It might be easier to, e.g., open a `png` device, save the diagram with transparent background (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/png.html) and use that for the inset. Sorry.